# getting View reference from Intent

Tags: android, maps, android-intent

I create a tabbed view with a list and a map, this is the code used to build the tab:

```
tabHost = getTabHost();

TabSpec tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab_map");
Intent i = new Intent().setClass(this, MyMapActivity.class);
tabSpec.setIndicator("Map",
 getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_mapmode))
 .setContent(i);
tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
```

now I need to access the **MapView** to set some **Overlay** on that map but if I try to do this:

```
MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.myMap);
```

the reference is always **null**, which is the right way? Thanks!!!

--
Luca

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use

intent.putExtra(MyMapActivity.Something, value);

depends upon where you call MapView as whether the view has been inflated yet or not..obviously if it has not been inflated yet you might get a null